# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de una vista a javascript usando ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Quiero pasar una variable de instancia `@datos` que viene del controlador; de la vista a un javascript embebido y no logro hacer que el javascript lo reconozca, anexo código:

**Controlador:**
*inicio_controller.rb*

```
def data
    @datos = [{ name: 'Pedacito', data: [["Muestra A",  5],["Muestra B", 17],["Muestra C", 23],["Muestra D",  7]] }]
end
```

**Vista:**
*data.slim*

```
script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" 

hr
#PieCustom1
hr

javascript:

    Highcharts.chart('PieCustom1', {
            chart:    {type: 'pie',},
            title:    {text: 'Titulo de pie Donut in Highcharts'},
            subtitle: {text: 'Subtitulo de pie Donut in Highcharts'},
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderRadius: 10,
                borderWidth: 3,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) + '%';
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                            innerSize: 100,
                            depth: 45,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{y} pedacitos',
                                distance: -45
                            }
                    }
            },
            series: '<%= "#{@datos}" %>',
    });
```

Comment: Interpolado con `#{@datos}` debería funcionar

Comment: Cuando es un arreglo simple, una cadena o un numero pasan bien, pero cuando es una arreglo, y dentro del arreglo hay un hash es donde se vuelve una galleta, agregue un console.log a la variable @datos y me trae esto: [{:name=&gt;&quot;Pedacito&quot;, :data=&gt;[[&quot;Muestra A&quot;, 5], [&quot;Muestra B&quot;, 17], [&quot;Muestra C&quot;, 23], [&quot;Muestra D&quot;, 7]]}]

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco cual es el formato que requieres para [`series`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series), pero deberías mapear los datos de acuerdo a las necesidades del parámetro y luego transformarlo a json. Algo como:

```
series: #{@datos.map{|d| d.loquesea}.to_json}
```

Puse `.map` como ejemplo, ya que insisto, no sé qué requieres, quizás necesites `select` u otra operación, pero lo importante es que cuando tenga tus datos de acuerdo a lo que pide highcharts, termines convirtiendo el resultado con `.to_json`, que es lo que sabrá interpretar por el lado de javascript.

Comment: Amigo Lagos, todavia estoy aprendiendo mucho sobre Ruby, de verdad te agradezco cuando te tomas tu tiempo en responder, me puedes ayudar un poquito en lo que quieres decir "loquesea", creo que se como trabajar con el helper map y el helper select, pero no veo como meter algo en esa parte. agradecido por tu respuesta. Ya borre la otra pregunta. porque estaba como duplicada y antes que me penalicen la borre.

Comment: Como te mencionaba, puedes revisar en la [documentación](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series) cual es el formato que highcharts espera en `series`. Si te es muy complicado, prueba a revisar [los ejemplos](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) (donde dice "view options") para ver como se pasa la información y adapta tu arreglo de hashes a algo similar a lo que sale en el ejemplo. Cometí un error en la respuesta, ya que como estaba, pasaba un String con el json a `series`. Con la última edición debería funcionar.